# Take user-defined range as input to function

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA in excel. I would like to write a custom function that takes a range defined by the user as input and then searches for a particular word within that range. So far, the following code works, but it only searches in the predefined range "a2:g2", but I would want something that would change to "a3:g3", etc as the user fills down:

```
Function findme()
    With Worksheets("Filtered").Range("a2:g2")
    Set c = .Find("XXXX", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
      findme = "Match Found"
    Else: findme = "No match"
    End If
End With
```

I thought this should work, but it does not. It returns "VALUE"

```
Function findme(myrange as range)
    With Worksheets("Filtered").Range(myrange)
    Set c = .Find("XXXX", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
      findme = "Match Found"
    Else: findme = "No match"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myrange doesn't get passed to the function as an address / string, it's an actual range. The way you use it in your code (`Worksheets("Filtered").Range(myrange)`) requires an address. You could keep your code and use `myrange.address` instead of just `myrange`, or you can use the fact that your variable is all you need to continue.

```
Function findme(myrange as range) as string
    With myrange
    Set c = .Find("XXXX", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
      findme = "Match Found"
    Else: findme = "No match"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: O yes nutsch. This is exactly the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. If the answer works for you, please accept it as a solution. Welcome to SO.